# Is "deterred" appropriate here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

Can I use "deterred" in this context?

Tori ran over to her grandfather, not deterred by the big beard he'd grown since she last saw him.

Comment: Idiomatically, native speakers would [usually](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+deterred+by%2Cundeterred+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20deterred%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cundeterred%20by%3B%2Cc0) use single-word ***undeterred*** in your cited context.

Answer (score 1):

There would have to be previous sentences or conversation that establish the beard as an obstacle or something that would deter (beards don't typically do that).  If the listener/reader is unaware of this, you need to use a different word, such as "intimidated" or "worried".

Comment: Could I also say "bothered" or "disturbed" do you think?

Comment: Or "distracted"?

Comment: Hmm. In my experience, babies and young children who haven't seen many / any men with beards are very often frightened by them. Especially if their first exposure is a relative or close friend of the parents, since they're quite likely to put their face very close to the infant (who then starts bawling for that very reason).

Answer (score 1):

The concept of being "deterred" by a beard makes perfect sense to me, and I don't think another concept like "frightened" is necessary. It's the most colorful and interesting option of any mentioned.
I prefer undeterred to "not deterred" b/c I feel it reads easier, but idiomatically, either are all right.